# Переходные глаголы и дополнения

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, дополнение

У меня возникла путаница с пониманием переходных глаголов. Насколько я помню со школы, переходный глагол требует после себя прямое дополнение в виде существительного или местоимения обычно в винительном падеже без предлога.

**Точный анализ и холодный расчёт позволяет класть на лопатки любого гуманитария.**

Здесь дополнение выражено инфинитивом.

**Нужно заранее предупреждать о подводных камнях и уберегать от ошибок.**

Глаголы "предупреждать" и "уберегать" являются переходными, но в предложении выше они почему-то и без прямого дополнения чувствуют себя неплохо.

**Я совсем не умею объяснять.**

То же самое.

Или всё-таки переходность — свойство глагола, которое заключается лишь в **способности** глагола присоединять прямое дополнение? Разъясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Точный анализ и холодный расчёт **позволяет (= дает возможность/способен) класть на лопатки**  любого гуманитария.

(2) Я совсем **не умею объяснять**.

1) В обоих предложениях **составное глагольное сказуемое**: модальная связка + основной глагол, **это не дополнение.**

2) У переходного глагола действие переходит на прямой объект,  **наличие прямого дополнения у переходного глагола  (сущ. в  В.п. или  в Р.п.) обязательно,** иначе действие не будет выраженным.

http://pedlib.ru/Books/6/0262/6_0262-410.shtml

3) **Объектный инфинитив** не является прямым дополнением, так как  обозначает не объект, а действие: он приказал стрелять.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Вас интересует переходность определенных глаголов, но Вы приводите не лучшие примеры для понимания этого вопроса. В частности, используете форму составного глагольного сказуемого, так что трудно понять, о каком глаголе идет речь.  Поэтому начинается обсуждение смежных вопросов, к теме не относящихся.

**Итак, Вас интересует переходность нескольких глаголов, не имеющих прямого дополнения.**

1) **Объяснить**. Согласно словарю, этот глагол переходный, на что указывает местоимение ЧТО в начале статьи. Объяснить — это сделать ясным/понятным предмет или явление. Это основное значение глагола, **но он может использоваться и как непереходный.** Это ваш пример: **я не умею объяснять.** Объект не назван, поэтому действие не может перейти на предмет. Сравнить (такой же пример): Ребенок уже читает, он читает книгу.

2) **Предупредить.** Предупредить (кого) людей об опасности, предупредить (что) болезнь/столкновение.

**Уберечь.** Уберечь (кого) людей от опасности.

Это переходные глаголы, **да только в Вашем примере объект пропущен или подразумевается из контекста, поэтому предложение неполное.** В этом **принципиальное отличие** этих глаголов от глагола ***читать***, который может быть переходным или непереходным (во втором случае там объект просто не нужен).

3) **Позволять**. В словаре указано, что глагол используется с инфинитивом, то есть это **разрешение на действие.** Глагол непереходный. А как же "позволять ребенку любые шалости"? Здесь **тоже подразумевается действие**: позволять шалить, позволять (делать) любые шалости.

**Вывод**. **Переходный глагол обязательно имеет прямое дополнение**, это следует из его определения. Если прямое дополнение отсутствует, то глагол или употреблен в непереходном значении, или дополнение пропущено в неполном предложении (его можно восстановить).

Comment: 1) В примере "я не умею объяснять" я имел в виду, что глагол "объяснять" переходный, но у него в этом предложении нет прямого дополнения. Не "уметь". 2) Как же тогда мой второй пример "предупреждать о подводных камнях и уберегать от ошибок"? Здесь объекта действия нет, при этом глагол переходный. Действие вполне выраженное.

Comment: 3) Вроде как наоборот. "Действие инфинитива должно относиться к подлежащему (это субъектный инфинитив). Если действие инфинитива относится к другому члену предложения (объектный инфинитив), то инфинитив не входит в состав сказуемого, а является второстепенным членом" (http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/703-14_sostavnye_skazuemye_sostavnoe_glagolnoe_skazuemoe.html).

Comment: Пожалуйста, посмотрите мой ответ в дополнении. Объектный и субъектный инфинитив  мы здесь обсуждать не будем, так как просто не поняли друг друга (говорили о разных вещах).

Comment: @Jasmin,  вы пишете, что "объектный инфинитив не является прямым дополнением". А каким же дополнением он является?

Comment: Он приказал солдатам стрелять.  Он приказал солдатам: "Стреляйте". Приказал (кому) солдатам. Действие адресовано объекту (косвенное дополнение). Приказал (что делать) стрелять. Объектный инфинитив обозначает действие, не совпадающее с действием субъекта. Возможно,  это особый вид дополнения. С другой стороны,  это содержание речи,  а  речь уже можно рассматривать  как прямой объект, который создается говорящим.  Может быть  это нечто близкое к прямому дополнению, но не отвечающее всем требованиям согласно определению. А вы задайте  этот вопрос на форуме, может быть, найдется ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Переходными называются глаголы, обозначающие действие, которое направлено на объект, выраженный **зависимым именем в форме вин. п.** (при наличии в предложении **отрицания такой вин. п. регулярно заменяется род. п.:** читал книгу – не читал книги).  Однако это не значит, что при переходном глаголе не может быть дополнение, выраженное инфинитивом. Особенностью инфинитива является то, что в предложении он может выполнять функцию любого члена предложения.Это сближает ее с именем существительным, которое тоже имеет способность употребляться в значении любого члена предложения.

Что касается глаголов "предупреждать" и уберегать", следует отметить, что многозначные глаголы в одних значениях могут быть переходными, в других – непереходными. Так, гл. читать является переходным и управляет вин. п. в знач. (воспринимать написанное): читать книгу, письмо; этот же глагол является непереходным в знач. (уметь воспринимать написанное) (Малыш уже читает), (заниматься чтением).  Упомянутые глаголы тоже являются многозначными, что дает возможность в одном из значений быть переходными, в других нет.

Однако по поводу упомянутых глаголов существует и другая точка зрения.Так например, в учебнике Н.М. Шанского, А.Н. Тихонова особый разряд составляют так называемые косвенно-переходные глаголы. К ним относятся возвратные и невозвратные глаголы, управляющие не винительным, а другими косвенными падежами существительных **(без предлогов и с предлогами).** Они обозначают обычно отношение к объекту или состояние субъекта, но не выражают перехода действия на объект: желать победы, ждать поезда, гордиться братом, надеяться **на успех, верить другу, думать о победе, помогать товарищу и т. п.» [Шанский, Тихонов, 1981, с. 185].**

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, переходность — это **способность** глагола иметь прямое дополнение. Если глагол переходный, он может либо иметь это самое прямое дополнение, либо не иметь, ср.: (1)«Иван Михайлович любит пить» и (2)«Машенька будет пить водку» — в примере № 1 глагол *пить* потенциально может иметь дополнение, но в данном примере его просто нет; в примере № 2 тот же самый переходный глагол имеет дополнение.

Возможно, стоит уточнить: переходный глагол особен именно своей способностью *беспредложного* управления.